# OKHttp put and post requests not working

Tags: php, android, okhttp, put

I'm trying to use OKHttp to send a request to my php backend. I'm using this code:

```
public static String putRequestWithHeaderAndBody(String url, String header, String jsonBody) throws IOException
{
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonBody);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .put(body) //PUT
            .addHeader("Authorization", header)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

I then try to read the put body from php using this line of code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

However, it always seems to be empty. I feel like I am making a silly mistake, I cannot seem to find out what is wrong though.

The request does return the correct response body when I send it using Postman.

Comment: are you try with postman ? try to send the same request on postman to see if you can catch the body from here.

Comment: If I send it with postman, the code seems to work!

Comment: can you please add an interceptor and put the logs on the post ?. https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: is it actually hitting your web service? please add the interceptor that @tebitoq asked with the Level.BODY level and paste the console logs

Comment: What is your request url?